# UITableView with 3 custom cells but 1 different

Tags: xcode, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a `TableView` and I have created custom cells for that `TableView` with images, labels..etc, But I want one cell to be different than the others with It's own content ( cells will get their data from a backend).
So how to create 2 different types of cells in the same `TableView`, and how to arrange them, for example put 1 type of cell between 2 others ?

Edit: My UITableView Class:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell: CellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

    let otherCell: OtherCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("otherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OtherCellTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...

    return myCell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a storyboard, just drag another `UITableViewCell` into the table view to be used as a prototype. Give it a unique and subclass (if necessary). In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` dequeue either the cell you're currently dequeueing, or this new one.

If you're not using a storyboard you'll need to either
`-registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` or 
`-registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` to make your other cell style available to the table view.

Here's a modified version of your code that should work:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if condition {
        let myCell: CellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...
        return myCell
    }
    else {
        let otherCell: OtherCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("otherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OtherCellTableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...
        return otherCell
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have a custom cell in "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:", If I added another one, which one will be returned? Check OP.

Comment: You get the one with the reuseIdentifier you specify. Right now it's the one with the "myCell" identifier. Give the other cell a different identifier, like "myOtherCell". You specify this in the properties pane in Interface Builder while the cell is selected.

Comment: Check OP, I edited the function, but now it is behaving strangely. When I return one cell the other shows up, if I click on it it gets changed to the other one. Problem is I can only return one of them.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a modified version of the code you posted.

Comment: Still nit quit right, I want to display both cells at the same time, not only that but each type should have different number of cells.

Comment: You can only display one cell on each call to -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. So you'll need to get that called more often by passing a larger number in -tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:. Or you could have one section for each data point, each with any number of rows.